# send & save data to a List view in android

Tags: android, arrays, string, listview, android-edittext

i want to create an app that have two activity's
the first activity have one EditText to write String on it & one Button to Send String that is in EditText
and activity two have one ListView to receive String from EditText & show it... 
for example the ListView can show 20 String received from activity one

i have no problem with send strings between activity
but i don't no how to get them & put them to ListView to show!

if you know about send & save data to a List view please help me :)

sorry for my English

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't push 1 value to an Activity, start the activity, show a ListView, go back and add more. The second Activity will typically restart with a clean state.

Your options include

1. building an Arraylist of all the items, then starting the new Activity while passing that list
2. Use Fragments to achieve a similar task as (1), but the hosting Activity holds the list
3. Use persistent storage like Sqlite to store individual records, start the second activity whenever, and use a CursorAdapter to display the data to a ListView